# ASP.NET MVC WebGrid add headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, header, webgrid

How can I add headers column names with spaces to my asp.net mvc webgrid? Could some one throw some idea on this?

```
 var str= "ProjectID,ProjectTitle,ProjectDescription";
 var headers = "Project ID,Project Title,Project Description";

    string[] columns = str.Split(',');
    string[] hdrs = headers.Split(',');

    var cols = new List<WebGridColumn>();
    foreach (var column in columns)
    {
        cols.Add(grid.Column(column));
    }

    @grid.GetHtml(columns: cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cols.Add(grid.Column(columnName: "column", header: "Column Name With Spaces"));
```